# Wait for background process

Tags: macos, applescript

I am creating an applescript that should wait for two processes to finish and then execute some logic. The first is an Application, which is easy to wait for.

```
set program to "Applications/xyz.app"

repeat until (application program is not running)
    delay 1
end repeat
```

Now for my background task that doesn't work since it is a directly called executable not an Application. If it helps the process is [aria2](https://aria2.github.io/). Could anyone tell me how this works, or point me in the right direction to find an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `pgrep` to look for the process id of a process called `aria2` like this:

```
do shell script "/usr/bin/pgrep aria2"
```

I don't have `aria2` so I am only guessing its process name - try it in the Terminal first to see if it works:

```
pgrep aria2
```

There will be no output if it is not running.

To see fuller output, run:

```
ps -aef | grep -i aria
```

If you want to check it in a loop, you could do this sort of thing:

```
set ariarunning to 0
repeat until ariarunning > 0
   try
      set ariarunning to do shell script "/usr/bin/pgrep aria"
   end try
   delay 1
end repeat
```

Comment: Thank you that works! If you don't mind a follow-up Question: how do i compare the return code? `repeat until ((do shell script "/usr/bin/pgrep aria2c") = "") ` delays until the program is closed but then returns with a script error "The command exited with a non-zero status"